Regex to update URLs missing HTTPS
I'm looking for a regex or another approach to prepend HTTPS to any existing URLs without it from a list in Google Sheets as well as any that are added in the future.
For example, domain.com would change to https://domain.com
Please note I have multiple domains within the sheet, and I want to use a find-and-replace function so domains are updated wherever they are in the sheet.

Use this formula (Where A2 is your url without the https)
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,"^https?:\/\/[\w\.]*"),A1,"https://" & A1)

Edit
function onEdit(e) {
  const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cell = e.range;
  const url = cell.getValue();
  if (/^(?<!https?:\/\/)[\w\.]+\.\w+/.test(url)) {
    cell.setValue("https://" + url)
  }
}

This uses a weird Regex syntax that I'm amazed actually works. Just slap this onto your Appscript editor then give it permission. If you input a url without the http:// or https://, then it will append an https:// to the url.
Edit#2
function onEdit(e) {
  const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cells = e.range;
  const urlList = cells.getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < urlList[i].length; j++) {
      const url = urlList[i][j];
      if (/^(?<!https?:\/\/)[\w\.]+\.\w+/.test(url)) {
        cells.getCell(i+1,j+1).setValue("https://" + url)
      }
    }
  }
}

This should deal with copy-pasting different values. I still don't understand why you need to append urls with https:// though. As for your other comment, do you have a really big dataset? Is it possible for you to just copy and paste the values onto the same cells? Sorry I took a while to getting back to you.

The formula works when you add new URLs or click on an existing URL to edit, but it doesn't replace automatically the domains that are missing HTTPS:// in the start

There is another issue with the script; if you add a bunch of URLs, it will change all URLs with the value in the first top cell.
